# Accessing Nested Hash Elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I have an ruby array that looks like this.

```
arr = [
  { "dag"=>{
      "tasks"=>[
        { "arguments"=>{
            "parameters"=>[
              { "name"=>"inputJson",
                "value"=>"{{workflow.parameters.inputJson}}"
              }
            ]
          },
          "name"=>"build-handler-workflow",
          "template"=>"build-handler-workflow"
        }
      ]
    },
    "name"=>"dag-build-handler-workflow"
  },
  { "container"=>{
      "args"=>[
        "{{inputs.parameters.inputJson}}"
      ],
      "command"=>["cowsay"],
      "image"=>"docker/whalesay:latest",
      "resources"=>{
        "requests"=>{
          "cpu"=>"100m",
          "memory"=>"100Mi"
        }
      }
    },
    "inputs"=>{
      "parameters"=>[
        {"name"=>"inputJson"}
      ]
    },
    "metadata"=>{
      "annotations"=>{
        "workflows.argoproj.io/progress"=>"0/10000"
      }
    },
    "name"=>"build-handler-workflow",
    "synchronization"=>{
      "semaphore"=>{
        "configMapKeyRef"=>{
          "key"=>"template",
          "name"=>"build-handler-config"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

How would I go about iterating through this array hash so I can get only image field. may be something like this

```
p arr['spec']['templates']['container']['image']
"image"=>"docker/whalesay:latest"
```

I have Tried map method to access hash values. not able to get valid results.

```
p arr.map{|e|"#{e["container"]}"}
["", "{\"args\"=>[\"{{inputs.parameters.inputJson}}\"], \"command\"=>[\"cowsay\"], \"image\"=>\"docker/whalesay:latest\", \"resources\"=>{\"requests\"=>{\"cpu\"=>\"100m\", \"memory\"=>\"100Mi\"}}}"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=[{"dag"=>{"tasks"=>[{"arguments"=>{"parameters"=>[{"name"=>"inputJson", "value"=>"{{workflow.parameters.inputJson}}"}]}, "name"=>"build-handler-workflow", "template"=>"build-handler-workflow"}]}, "name"=>"dag-build-handler-workflow"}, {"container"=>{"args"=>["{{inputs.parameters.inputJson}}"], "command"=>["cowsay"], "image"=>"docker/whalesay:latest", "resources"=>{"requests"=>{"cpu"=>"100m", "memory"=>"100Mi"}}}, "inputs"=>{"parameters"=>[{"name"=>"inputJson"}]}, "metadata"=>{"annotations"=>{"workflows.argoproj.io/progress"=>"0/10000"}}, "name"=>"build-handler-workflow", "synchronization"=>{"semaphore"=>{"configMapKeyRef"=>{"key"=>"template", "name"=>"build-handler-config"}}}}]
```

Code

```
arr.each do |hash|
  if hash['container']
    puts hash['container']['image']
  end
end
```

Or you could use dig method

```
arr.each { |hash| puts hash.dig('container', 'image') if hash['container'] }
```

Output

```
docker/whalesay:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, also `dig` is pretty useful when navigating through hashes

```
images = []
arr.each do |item|
  img = item.dig("container", "image")
  images << img unless img.nil?
end

p images
```

Comment: or `images = arr.filter_map { |e| e.dig("container", "image") }`

Comment: Thank you this got me working, I am able to get images

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know in which nested hashes in a given array or hash (here an array) a given key can be found, and want to return an array containing the values of that key throughout the given object,  you can use the following recursive method.

```
def doit(obj, key)
  case obj
  when Array
    obj.each_with_object([]) do |o, arr|
      if [Array, Hash].include?(o.class)
        res = doit(o, key)
        res.each { |v| arr << v }
      end  
    end
  when Hash
    obj.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v), arr|
      if k == key
        arr << v
      elsif [Array, Hash].include?(v.class)
        res = doit(v, key)
        res.each { |v| arr << v }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
doit(arr, "image")
  #=> ["docker/whalesay:latest"]
```

```
doit(arr, "name")
  #=> ["inputJson", "build-handler-workflow", "dag-build-handler-workflow",
  #    "inputJson", "build-handler-workflow", "build-handler-config"]
```

```
doit(arr[0]["dag"]["tasks"], "name")
  #=> ["inputJson", "build-handler-workflow"]
```

```
doit(arr, "inputs")
  #=> [{"parameters"=>[{"name"=>"inputJson"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for providing all of these alternatives, All of these methods works fine but I prefer this one:

```
images = arr.filter_map { |e| e.dig("container", "image") }
```

I am able to get the data from array.